# How does Stanford CRF encode NER string features?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-extraction, named-entity-recognition, stanford-nlp, java

Most features created by the `NERFeatureFactory` are strings e.g. from `usePrev`, `useNext`, `useNGrams` etc. From my understanding, that's too many tokens to fit in a dictionary or to use embeddings. I don't see how the `UNKNOWN` embedding would bring any value given that most features are not known words. I've been looking at the code on [Github](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/tree/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/ie) but haven't figured it out yet.

`I love New York!` > `love` > `love-I-W-PW`, `love-New-W-NW`, `#lo#`, `#ov#`, `#ve#` etc